# Como posso adicionar objetos em uma lista dinamicamente através das views?

Tags: java-ee, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Estou com uma dúvida em relação ao `Spring MVC`.

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema usando `HTML5` na `View`, e como renderizador estou utilizando o `thymeleaf`.

Por exemplo, caso eu tenha uma classe `Produto`, e esta tenha uma lista de `Endereços`, existe um meio pra mim ir dando `add` na lista, considerando que o `springmvc` é um `framework action based`?

Answer (score -1):

> Classe: Produto
>
> Lista: Enderecos
>
> Objetivo: Adicionar um item na lista através do view.

Você pode usar um submit no seu view, que pegue os parâmetros necessários pra sua lista endereços e leve para o seu método, por exemplo:

**Código do view:**

```
<form th:action="@{/produtos/addEndereco}" th:object="${endereco}" method="POST">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Logradouro"
                th:field="*{logradouro}"/> 
        <input type="number" placeholder="numero" th:field="*{numero}"/>
        <button type="submit">Adicionar</button>
</form>
```

No seu controller, você vai chamar o método que adiciona um item na lista.

**Controller:**

```
        @Controller
        @RequestMapping("/produtos")
        public class ProdutosController{

           @Autowired
           Produtos produtos;

           @RequestMapping(value="/addEndereco",method = RequestMethod.POST)
           public String adicionarEndereco(Endereco endereco){
               this.produtos.addEndereco(endereco);
               return "redirect:/produtos";
           }
        }
```

**Model:**

```
@Service
public class Produtos {

   private static List<Endereco> enderecos = new ArrayList<>();

   public void addEndereco(Endereco endereco){
      enderecos.add(endereco);
   }
}
```

E o seu bean de Endereço:

```
public class Endereco {

   String logradouro;
   int numero;

   ...
}
```